# What's the part of Cross Product in Electromagnetic induction?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Base on Cross Product (Right Hand Rule), Vector **a** into the screen, **b** goes down, then **cross product** goes right...

e.g. If the Magnetic Field **B** is going into the screen and the electron is going down **v**... then eventually the electron will go to the right  **f**...

Does that mean whatever that goes down through the Magnetic field will experience Lorentz Force?

e.g. If the Magnetic Field **B** (vector **a**) is going into the screen and a **piece of wood** is going down **v** (vector **b**)... then eventually it will go to the right  **f** (**cross product**) ?

Comment: Your piece of wood is presumably electrically neutral, so it wouldn't be affected either way. Moving in a magnetic field, it would feel an electric field in its rest frame, but unless the strength of that field changes from place to place, this wouldn't affect the wood's movement.

Answer (score 1):

Important thing to notice is to understand that lorentz force acts only on charged particles,but every particle is not charged.For instance a piece of wood is neutral so net force on it will be zero.